# use bash to pass 2 variables to a Makefile

Tags: bash, make

I have a bash script which outputs calls to my make file.

```
#!/bin/bash
mylist=(
    'SAMPLES_OUT=$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1‌​.gff'
    'SAMPLES_OUT=$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me2​.gff'
    'SAMPLES_OUT=$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me3​.gff'
    'SAMPLES_OUT=$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me4​.gff'
    'SAMPLES_OUT=$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me5​.gff'
)



for SAMPLES_out in "${mylist[@]}";
do
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT=\'${SAMPLES_out}\'
done
```

This is the makefile:

```
IN_DIR = /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/namesorted_bams
list_samples = $(shell ls $(IN_DIR)/*$(1)* $(IN_DIR)/*$(2)* $(IN_DIR)/*$(3)* | sed 's/\.namesorted\.bam/\.gene\.read\.count/g')
#SAMPLES_OUT := $(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)

all: $(SAMPLES_OUT)

GFF := /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1.gff
GFF_TEMP := $(GFF).temp.gff

$(GFF_TEMP): $(GFF)
    sed 's/\*/./g' $< > $@

%.gene.read.count: %.namesorted.bam $(GFF_TEMP)
    htseq-count -t exon -m intersection-strict -f bam -r name -s no $^ > $@
```

I am trying to pass 2 variables out of the same array to my makefile but this does not seem to work properly as well if I do it like this in my bash scripts array list:

```
'$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1‌​.gff'
```

Unfortunately it seems that makefile cannot deal with this kind of constructs. How can i pass both variables to my makefile without any command line problems. So how to circumvent $(call) been seen as a command line call. The 2 variables i want to pass to the makefile are GFF and SAMPLES_OUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't support nested arrays or any other complicated data structures.

As the number of arguments is known, though, you can create two arrays, one for each argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

samples=(
    '$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)'
)

gff=(
    /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1‌​.gff
    /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me2​.gff
    /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me3​.gff
    /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me4​.gff
    /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me5​.gff
)

for (( idx=0; idx<${#samples[@]}; ++idx )) ; do
    make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT="${samples[idx]}" GFF="${gff[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks again for this clear explanation and help. Can i assume that the first gff file will be linked to the first sample file? Since i need to make sure they match otherwise a wrong file may be created by the makefile.

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Yes, they are linked by the position in the array (represented by the `$idx` variable).

Comment: sure, nice and clear as always :) Thank you!